# How can I unzip a specific folder?

Tags: java, tomcat, ant, unzip

How can I unzip a specific folder with Ant?

Specifically, I have downloaded apache-tomcat-6.0.29.zip which contains the folder "apache-tomcat-6.0.29".  I want Ant to unzip everything under "apache-tomcat-6.0.29" but not include "apache-tomcat-6.0.29" in the top of hierarchy.

I've tried a bunch of things, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Here's my latest attempt:

```
<unzip dest="${release.dir}/image/tomcat" src="${tomcat.zip}">
    <patternset>
        <include name="apache-tomcat-6.0.29/*"/>
    </patternset>
</unzip>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use a [mapper](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/mapper.html) within the unzip task to change the paths written.

```
<unzip dest="${release.dir}/image/tomcat" src="${tomcat.zip}">
    <patternset>
        <include name="apache-tomcat-6.0.29/*"/>
    </patternset>
    <mapper>
        <globmapper from="apache-tomcat-6.0.29/*" to="*"/>
    </mapper>
</unzip>
```

Comment: Thanks.  This worked: <mapper type="glob" from="apache-tomcat-6.0.29/*" to="*"/>

Comment: You don't need the pattern set section either.

Comment: I am able to get away with the folder but none of my files inside sub-folder gets copied to destination directory. Any idea what could be the reason? For ex: w.r.t above example, none of the files in bin folder is copied and bin folder is empty. I am using the stuff exactly the same way you have mentioned.

Comment: What to do if I don't know the root folder name? E.g. future versions.

Answer (score 3):

The following works as long that there is a single directory in the tomcat archive.

```
<untar src="${release.dir}" dest="${tomcat.tar.gz}" compression="gzip">
  <cutdirsmapper dirs="1" />
</untar>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<unzip dest="${release.dir}/image/tomcat" src="${tomcat.zip}">
    <patternset>
        <!-- add another star -->
        <include name="apache-tomcat-6.0.29/**"/>
    </patternset>
</unzip>
```